# Composer : Why some of my packages got automatically removed on installing a new package

Tags: composer-php

[My composer status while installing the new package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fV8e5.png)

I tried installing stripe package on yii2 via composer. It got installed successfully but also removed some of the packages automatically. I didn't edit composer.json or lock file, I just execute the composer require command to install the package. Why the composer removed those packages and how can I recover them back? Is there any way to prevent it in future?
Thanks!

Comment: Are these packages needed in your project? If yes, why are they not listed in your `composer.json`? If not, why do you care about them being uninstalled?

Comment: @NicoHaase, that's what my concern is. I didn't touched the composer.json file. I'm not sure but other developer might be already using it in other part of the project (which I'm not aware of).

Comment: Well, your test suite would provide information about this - and if one of the other developers used packages that are not listed in `composer.json`, you should check through version control when these packages where added for which reason. But without sharing more details, it's impossible to provide help.

Answer (score 1):

Say your project **A** requires dependency **B**.

Version `1.1.x` of dependency **B** requires package **C**.

Now if you update to version `1.2.x` of dependency **B** which does **NOT** depend on package **C** anymore `composer` will automatically detect the orphaned dependency and therefore remove package **C**.

If you still want package **C** to be available to your application after the update you need to explicitly `require` it - making it an **explicit** dependency instead of an **implicit** one (installed as a dependency of another package).

`composer` automatically updates the other dependencies of your project (respecting the existing version constraints your `composer.json`) if you invoke `composer require`.

To prevent automatic dependency updates use:

```
composer require --no-update <package>
```

Comment: Thanks! I got it, but still is there any way to get back (revert) those packages automatically (without installing them again manually)? I'm not sure but I might be already using one of those plugins in some other module.