# Composer removing packages after installing Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel, package, composer-php, laravel-sanctum

I am trying to install Laravel Sanctum following the instructions on Laravel's website: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum

I run this command `composer require laravel/sanctum` and Laravel Sanctum is successfully installed:

> Using version ^2.11 for laravel/sanctum ./composer.json has been
> updated Loading composer repositories with package information

However, it seems like installing Sanctum is also removing default Laravel Packages:

> Package operations: 12 installs, 82 updates, 7 removals
>
> - Removing symfony/polyfill-php70 (v1.18.0)

**So my question is:**

How do I install Sanctum without removing other packages?

Comment: Are you sure it just doesn't update this package.?

Comment: Yes, everyting seems to be OK, `composer.json` file and everthing, it just removes other packages that were not supposed to be removed, including Laravel deault packages. I checked the folder and the files were indeed deleted.

Comment: Have you checked whether these packages are really required by any package? If you need them, put them in your own `composer.json`

Comment: They come with Laravel, so it should be there.

Comment: If Laravel requires them, Composer won't delete them. Can you revert the change and run `composer why symfony/polyfill-php70`?

Comment: I tried running the command and I got this: `Could not find package "symfony/polyfill-php70" in your project` then I tried running the command on my backup and I got this: `symfony/polyfill-intl-idn  v1.18.0  requires  symfony/polyfill-php70 (^1.10)` .

Comment: Then go further. Check why `symfony/polyfill-intl-idn` is installed. Maybe an old version of Laravel requires it, while the changes you've performed updated the list of required packages? Otherwise, it could help to share the **full** output of the initial command, and not just an excerpt

Comment: It's required for email validations, just checked. Either way, I think I kinda asked a duplicated question, my apologies. I found an "answer" here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62132516/composer-why-some-of-my-packages-got-automatically-removed-on-installing-a-new. I just ran `composer require --no-update laravel/sanctum` and it worked as it didn't update packages, therefore didn't remove any packages, but if Composer is removing packages, it means I don't need them anymore, so I think it's a bad thing keeping unecessary packages, but at the same time, my site doesn't work without them.

Comment: If your site does not work without any package, why not require that package properly?

Comment: Acually it's like you said, everything was automatically handled by Laravel and Composer, the thing is that the classes weren't removed from the autoload file, so it was looking for files that don't exist. I had to remove them manually. It's working now. Thank you.